# @expo/config-plugins issues arises when when using react native firebase with react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

```
@react-native-firebase/app@17.4.2
│ └── @expo/config-plugins@5.0.4
├─┬ @react-native-firebase/auth@17.4.2
│ └── @expo/config-plugins@5.0.4
└─┬ expo@48.0.10
  ├─┬ @expo/cli@0.6.2
  │ ├── @expo/config-plugins@6.0.1 deduped
  │ └─┬ @expo/prebuild-config@6.0.0
  │   └── @expo/config-plugins@6.0.1 deduped
  ├── @expo/config-plugins@6.0.1
  └─┬ @expo/config@8.0.2
    └── @expo/config-plugins@6.0.1 deduped
```

i have a compatibility issues when using @react-native-firebase/app@17.4.2 in our expo project.

After too much research, I found that the issues arises because @expo/config-plugins@6.0.1 uses by many of other packages but when i install react native firebase they uses @expo/config-plugins@5.0.4.
i don't know how can i fix it, please anyone can help me.

I will try to install manually this packages, but i got nothing from this as well.